# Why isn't Firefox scaled properly in a multi-monitor setup?

Tags: 16.04, firefox, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and Firefox 50.1 with an external monitor attached to my laptop. My laptop screen is 14-inch 1080p which has a scale factor of 1.25 in System Settings. My external monitor is 22-inch 1080p which has a scale factor of 1. And in my about:config, I set the layout.css.devPixelsPerPx to -1.0.

When I set the scale factor to match the smallest controls in System Settings, Firefox becomes tiny on my laptop screen. Not completely unusable, but annoying.

Is there anyway to get per-monitor DPI scaling on Firefox? Especially natively without installing new extensions? Firefox can already handle this on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following AutoHiDPI extension for Firefox and it scales pretty well in Ubuntu 17.04:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/autohidpi/

Comment: @Zanna: You're right, whoops!